# FileStream в c++ и c#

Tags: c#, filestream, c++

Доброго времени суток!
Битый час не могу разобраться с вопросом.

Кусочек кода на с++

```
unsigned short cpoint1;
TFileStream* wfs1=new TFileStream("Signal1.wav",fmCreate);
for (i=0; i<m ; i++) 
 {
  cpoint1 = wfmmas1[i];
  wfs1->Write(&cpoint1,2);
 }
 delete wfs1;
```

Пытаюсь переписать на с#

```
ushort cpoint1;
FileStream wfs1 = new FileStream("Signal1.wav", FileMode.Create);
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
for (i=0; i<m ; i++) 
 {
  cpoint1 = wfmmas1[i];
  wfs1.Write(uniEncoding.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(astr)), 2, uniEncoding.GetByteCount(Convert.ToString(astr))-2);
 }
wfs2.Close();
```

Проблема в том, что файлы, создаваемые в первом и втором случае разные.
Буду рад любой помощи! =)

Comment: По конкретней что у вас не получается!!

Answer (score 2):

ushort cpoint1;

```
        FileStream wfs1 = new FileStream("Signal1.wav", FileMode.Create);
        UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            cpoint1 = wfmmas1[i];
            wfs1.Write(uniEncoding.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(cpoint1)), 0,
                uniEncoding.GetByteCount(Convert.ToString(cpoint1))); 
        }
        wfs1.Close();
```

Comment: Igor нашел мои косяки, но результат все равно был другой.
вышел из ситуации следующим образом:
ushort cpoint1;
FileStream wfs1 = new FileStream("Signal1.wav", FileMode.Create);
for (i=0; i<m ; i++) 
 {
    cpoint1 = wfmmas1[i];
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(cpoint1);
    wfs1.Write(bytes, 0,2);
 }
wfs1.Close();